# Save data from dropdownlist using selectlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

I am trying to save data using `SelectListItem`. I have managed to display the data but, I can't think of a way to save a selected item into the database. 
My controller methods are:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ProposerID = new SelectList(db.Proposers, "ID", "ProposerName");

    List<SelectListItem> projectType = new List<SelectListItem>();
    projectType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Development", Value = "1" });
    projectType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Research", Value = "2" , Selected = true});
    projectType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Hybrid", Value = "3" });
    projectType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "4" });
    ViewBag.ProjectType = projectType; 
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(
 [Bind(Include = "ID,ProjectTitle,Description,ProposedDate,ProjectType,ProjectStatus,ProjectDifficulty,ProposerID")] Project project)
{
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && ModelState != ModelState)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Something went wrong!! Please try again.";
       // Error message
    } 
    ViewBag.ProposerID = new SelectList(db.Proposers, "ID", "ProposerName", project.ProposerID);
    return View(project);
}
```

and my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectType", "")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I have managed to display the data but, I am confused on how to get selected item and save it.

My Model is:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Project Title")]
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [DisplayName("Project Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Proposed Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ProposedDate { get; set; }
    // Development or Research etc.
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Project Type")]
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }
    // Project Is Taken or Not
    [DisplayName("Project Status")]
    public ProjectStatus ProjectStatus { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Project Difficulty")]
    public ProjectDifficulty ProjectDifficulty { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Proposer")]
    public int ProposerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Proposer Proposer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where do you bind ViewBag.ProjectType to dropdownlist in the view?

Comment: Yes, I bind my ViewBag.ProjectType in my View as "ProjectType".

Comment: The code posted doesn't do any binding between ViewBag.Project and dropdownlist "ProjectType". In your view bind it this way @Html.DropDownList("ProjectType", ViewBag.ProjectType as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>).  Then in you action method check for the parameter "ProjectType" and you'll see the selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change you `ViewBag` key so it is different than the model property name:

```
ViewBag.ProjectTypeOptions = projectType;
```

and in your view use `DropDownListFor` helper this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.ProjectType, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjectTypeOptions,"Value","Text"))
```

now you will get selecred item value posted in Model in `ProjectType` property.

and your model should have property of type `string` not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` like this:

```
public class Project
{
   public string ProjectType { get;set;}
   ............ 
   ............
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried as you mentioned but, I am getting this error The ViewData item that has the key 'ProjectType' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. Do you know why?

Comment: @HarshPanchal I have modified my post Check updated post

Comment: I have tried that as well but still receiving this error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items  at this line of code @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectType, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjectTypeOptions, "Value", "Text"))